# Read from a file different types of variables (1 per line)

Tags: c++, file, input, parameters

I have an app written in C++ that gets some parameters from an extern txt file. This file has one variable per line and they're different kinds like:

> 0
>   0.8
>   C:\Documents\Textfile.txt
>   9

I tried something like this (not exactly as I don't have the code now)

```
    FILE* f;
char line[300];
f = fopen("parameters.txt", "r");

    scanf(line, val1);
    scanf(line, val2);
    scanf(line, val3);
    fclose(f);
```

But it doesn't work, also tried with fgets and fgetc with some changes and didn't work. Any help or idea? The variables are always the same number and have the same types in each place (so I think I don't need any while or loop). Thank you so much for your help in this newbie problem that is driving me crazy.

**EDIT:**
Actually this was the exact code I saw at another solution here

```
sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", tp);
sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", mcl);
sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", pmt);
sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", amx);
```

It didn't work, it compiled but the program crashed so I changed it into scanf and it didn't crashed but the variables were empty.

Comment: The first argument to `scanf` is supposed to be a format string.

Comment: Pleae show your actual code. The code you posted is so far from right it's hard to comment. You're missing the format string, you called `scanf` instead of `fscanf` (so it's not reading from the file), and you haven't shown the declarations of `valN`.

Comment: Question is tagged as C++ but your code is using C standard library for I/O ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++ (not just C) I suggest you use the standard iostreams library instead of C stdio. In particular, std::ifstream is good at reading formatted data from a file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// ...

std::ifstream f("parameters.txt");

int val1;
f >> val1;

double val2;
f >> val2;

std::string val3;
std::getline(f, val3);

// etc
```

Depending on your application, you might want error checks as well. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/ for iostream details.

Comment: It seems to work but it doesn't write anything on any variable (seen at the execution)

Comment: Is parameters.txt in the current working directory? After opening the file with ifstream's constructor, check the result of f.fail(). If it returns true, the file couldn't be opened for some reason (probably because it couldn't be found).

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is for reading input from `stdin`, it has nothing to do with `FILE`.

If you want to read a text file line by line, I would not recommend `FILE`.  It is more complicated and is more suited for binary reading.  I would go with `ifstream` instead, here is a very simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    ifstream stream("parameters.txt");
    string line;

    /* While there is still a line. */
    while(getline(stream, line)) {
        // variable 'line' is now filled with everyone on the current line,
        // do with it whatever you want.
    }

    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried but it gets nothing from the file. I try to print the line to see what it got and it was empty. Also if I try to fill the variable with what's in the line, there's nothing.

Comment: are you sure the file was even opened?  Do you have the correct path?  Note that `line` is an `std::string` class, not a `char *` so it's slightly different in its usage.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, it was a problem related to that (std::string - char*)